# HTML/Javascript Input Image Trigger Action on Accept

Tags: javascript, html, image-uploading

I am busy writing a simple Image Input and am trying to get it to show a little GIF while it is processing the Image.

Basic HTML

```
<input id="input_file" name="file" type="file" />
```

Main Javascript Trigger

```
$("#input_file").on("change", function() {
    displayImageLoader();
    uploadImage();
});

function displayImageLoader() {
    // logic removed for testing
    console.log("LOADER");
}

function uploadImage() {
    // logic removed for testing
    console.log("UPLOAD");
}
```

The minor issue that I'm having is that after the image is selected in the file browser, there is a delay before the on change triggers.

In most cases the delay is longer than the image processing, so the Image is selected, then 1sec/2sec or so delay, then the on change triggers, then the loader is seen for less than second then the image is uploaded.

I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger functions as soon as the file browser has been confirmed (if confirmed)

Comment: what is the process ? you mean an async file downloader ? you want to show an ajax loading gif ?

Comment: At the moment it is only console.log, the delay is still there

Comment: maybe it's because image size or your computer ram, browser speed or other system problems etc.

Comment: I think it's because it has to get the Local Path from my machine and pass it into the Browser but how do I trigger a function before that happens?

Comment: you can't, because it's depend to user action, first you should click on browse file and select file then show the photo !

Comment: It's doing that currently, just the bit between the Select File and Show Photo is the problem

Comment: ok, check this example. maybe helps you : https://codepen.io/mobifreaks/pen/LIbca

Comment: That one is doing the same thing though, there's a delay between clicking Open and when the Image Path appears in the browser, I want to trigger an action immediately after Open is clicked